# How to set accessibilityIdentifier for a title of a viewcontroller in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility, appium

The problem is that I can't set accessibilityIdentifier for a title of a viewcontroller that is inside of a NavigationController. I need to set it for testing purposes for Appium.

The simplest solution seemed to be setting something like `navigationItem.titleView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "titleID"`
But that never worked for me. I tried several different options and setting it in different places - but when checking via View Hierarchy could not find my accessibilityIdentifier there.

The only option that worked for me was something like this

```
typelet titleLabel = UILabel()
titleLabel.text = "My title"
titleLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "titleID"
navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel
```

But I would rather not using second approach and hope that it is possible to set accessibilityIdentifier just for default element and I'm just missing something here :)